# elasticsearch regexp don't work

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I need to make a regexp on elasticsearch to filtre some data.
The field I filter on is the name of person. The data are not always well formatted (sometimes, there is no first name, sometimes, the family name is followed by a period or a comma or 'comma+first name' or 'point+first name'....).

For example, using *"bouchard"* I get the following matches:

```
 "bouchard", "bouchard, m.", "bouchard, j.", "bouchard j.p.", "bouchard. j.p."
```

I need also to exclude name who begin with same prefixe like *"bouchardat"*.

I tried many regexps and finally found that an exclusion may yield better results:

```
   "query" :  { "regexp" : {
                    "RECORDEDBY" : "bouchard([^a-z].*)"
    }}
```

This doesn't work because it returns *"bouchard, m.", "bouchard, j.", "bouchard j.p."* but not *"bouchard. j.p."* and not *"bouchard"*.

I try some regexps with + and .*  but they don't work.

```
( "bouchard([^a-z].*.*)" "bouchard([^a-z]*+.*)")
```

To make it clear, I want to allow:

```
bouchard
bouchard, m.
bouchard, j.
bouchard j.p.
bouchard. j.p.
```

I want to exclude

```
bouchardat
```

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What entries do you allow, and which ones do you want to disallow? The documentation says that Elasticsearch regexes are always anchored, so `"RECORDEDBY" : "bouchard"` will only allow `bouchard`, and `"RECORDEDBY" : "bouchard.+"` should allow any values starting with `bouchard`.

Comment: Sorry.
I want to exclude "bouchardat" and to allow : "bouchard", "bouchard, m.", "bouchard, j.", "bouchard j.p.","bouchard. j.p." and all the entries with the same name followed by a combination of space/point/coma and any word.

Comment: Then, try using `bouchard[^a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: bouchard[^a-zA-Z]* return only "bouchard" but not  "bouchard, m.", "bouchard, j.", "bouchard j.p.","bouchard. j.p."

Comment: "bouchard[^a-zA-Z]*.*" return "bouchard","bouchard, m.","bouchard, j.","bouchard j.p.","bouchardat" . 
it miss "bouchard. j.p." and allow ""bouchardat"

Comment: What about "bouchard~[a-zA-Z]*" with `"flags": "COMPLEMENT"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you could use a [conditional operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) to exclude every `[a-z]` suffix if no special character like '', '`.`', or '`,`' follows the word you are looking for:

```
((bouchard)+?([ .,]+)[ ,.a-zA-Z]*)|(bouchard[^a-zA-Z]?)
```

This regexp returns for the condition (there has to be `[ .,]+`):

```
bouchard
bouchard, m.
bouchard, j.
bouchard j.p.
bouchard. j.p.
```

and ignores the stuff after the pipe `|` where no `[ .,]+` applies:

```
bouchardat
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oM6oQ2/3)

Comment: thanks for the explained solution. unfortunaly it don't  return "bouchard". the caractere comma, space and point didn't need to be escaped ?

Comment: Of course, the ```?``` was missing at the end. Updated and added reges101 link.

Comment: And of course, you want to capture the whole group, so updated once more.

Comment: No need to excape those characters.

Comment: thank you very much. thank for the Regex101 site too.

Comment: `(bouchard+[^a-zA-Z]?)` this one will match bouchardddddd (infite number of d) I don't see the reason of this `+` after d at all

Comment: if a also want to return data like this : `bouchard. [j.p.]` and `bouchard. (j.p.)`
Please is this wright ? `((bouchard)+?([\[( .,]+)[ ,.\]\)a-zA-Z]*)|(bouchard[^a-zA-Z]?)`

Comment: This one works for me `((bouchard)+?([\[\( .,]+)[ ,.a-zA-Z\]\)]*)|(bouchard[^a-zA-Z]?)`, also see v6 https://regex101.com/r/oM6oQ2/6. For this regexp, you gotta put the closing `], )`'s into the then-clause of the condition.